# Putting a char in an exact stringposition

Tags: string, excel, vba, char

Is there a way to put a Char in this case a "0" into a string?
I'd like to put a zero at position 8

For example:

device 4 -> device 04

I hope i could explain the problem well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newString = Left(existingString, 7) & "0" & Mid(existingString, 8)` is one way.

`&` is the *string concatenation* operator in VBA, the two argument `Mid` runs from a given position to the end of a string.

Comment: Perfect, the counting starts a 0 so if you want at eight position u need to write 7 and 8 .

Thank you very much.

gonna upvote in 3 mins :)

Comment: Isn't the third parameter (num_chars) mandatory for MID though?

Comment: Hm, so it's the exact opposite of LEFT and RIGHT where the second parameter is optional in a worksheet but not in VBA

Comment: Yup. Perhaps the VBA developers and the Excel developers were a little out of touch with each other.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done using a worksheet function:

```
=REPLACE(D1,8,0,"0")
```

[image]

And the `Replace` method is also a member of the WorksheetFunction in VBA, so you could write it as a VBA function also.  Note that this is different from the VBA Replace function.